# fatal error: FreeRTOSConfig.h: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, arm, freertos

When I am compiling FreeRTOS for my STM32F103C8T6 I am getting this error :

```
    fatal error: FreeRTOSConfig.h: No such file or directory
```

I have all required header and source files and also defined all the Include Paths, but the compiler is still throwing the same error. But if I move *FreeRTOSConfig.h* to **"/FreeRTOS_demo/freeRTOSv10/Source/include/"** then the compiler builds without any error.
I also have successfully compiled and debugged blinky project (without FreeRTOS) with the same set of hardware and software.

I am using the following setup to compile FreeRTOS :

1. OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
2. Ecplise C/C++ IDE Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
3. FreeRTOS v10.0.1
4. STLink-V2 debugger
5. Toolchain: arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 7-2017-q4-major)7.2.1

Why is Eclipse unable to find this file in spite of defining its location in Include Path?

Comment: Either you build it wrong, the setup is broken or there's a bug in the code. It's impossible to tell without looking at the whole and ruling out various errors, but that's far too wide for a question here. You'll have to do some digging first. Oh, btw, you have not asked any question!

Comment: Here is the screen record of the entire process: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VaZiMYJMpNaeHYIjYGn-K6cDs2LcjbWt

Comment: BTW I also tried rebuilding the index of the project and recompile still  the error persists